# Trigonometry in Geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

One of my friends gave me this problem. Initially I thought that this would be easy but i tried this for two days unable to do this in a proper manner.

[image]

**There is a circle with an angle A located at the center of the circle**

***Prove that:  $\sin A < A < \tan A$***

Comment: Include what you've tried so far, please.

Comment: $\tan(3\pi/4) < 0 < 3\pi/4$ so apparently you are missing assumptions.

Comment: Maybe superb jhon means :$A$ is an acute angel

Comment: Probably! superb jhon should *tell us*.

Comment: we need A to be a positive acute angle for this. (A=0 fails)

Comment: See the  many answers to [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Comment: @Khosrotash I would fear the wings of an acute angel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
The area of $\triangle ABC$ is $\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)$.  The area of the colored wedge is $\frac{1}{2}x$, and the area of $\triangle ABD$ is $\frac{1}{2}\tan(x)$. 
 By inclusion, we get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\tan(x)\ge\frac{1}{2}x\ge\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)\tag{1}
$$

Comment: What s/w do you use to create that picture?

Comment: Combining from paint and desmos.com ....

Answer (score 1):

On $(0,\pi/2)$ we have $\cos t < 1 < \sec^2 t.$ Integrating each term from $t=0$ to $t=A$ gives your desired inequality as long as $0<A<\pi/2.$ [inequality false for at least some $A$ not in this range.]

Of course this proof is usually done via a diagram; see a calc book.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way between two points is the straight line. This establishes $$\sin \dfrac A2<\dfrac A2.$$

Then the area of the triangle formed with the tangent to the circle is larger than the area of the sector, hence

$$\frac A2<\tan\frac A2.$$

Replace $\dfrac A2$ by $A$.